Add information to list of matrices
I have a folder of 720x720 matrices that I have been uploading into R, doing some quick modifications, and adding to a list using a for loop. Each matrix is the pixel values of a binary image of a 2D path of an animal. I've been reducing the list of matrices to then generate a heat map of all the animal paths overlaid.
### create a list of the files from  target directory
file_list <- list.files(path="./PathCSVs/")

#create list to add matrices to
matlist <- list()

  # cycle through files in each folder
  for(i in 1:length(file_list)){
    temp <- read.delim(file = paste("./PathCSVs/", file_list[i], sep = ""))

    #change column names
    names(temp) <- c(1:720)

    #rescale values between 0 and 1
    temp <- rescaleeb(temp)
    
    # Time to create/add to list
    matlist <- append(matlist, list(temp))
  
  }

#sum matrices in the list
summat <- Reduce("+", matlist)

#add column with row numbers
summat$row_num <- seq.int(nrow(summat))

#make data long for heat map
imagemelt <- melt(summat, id="row_num")

#create heat map
ggplot(imagemelt, aes(variable, row_num)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_viridis(name = "Number\nof Contacts",
                     limits = c(0, 35),
                     breaks = c(0, 10, 20, 30)) 

This code creates a heat map using all the matrices in the folder, which represents multiple species. Now I would like to split this up and generate heat maps by species. The titles of the individual matrices in the folder could be used to link back to the species ID of the matrix. My initial idea was to upload the files with their file name, and then somehow link that to speciesIDs to then filter by species before plotting, but I can't figure out how to upload the files with the file names, or add a title after the fact.
I've tried a few different options, including adding this into the for loop after rescaling the matrix.
#Add file name to each matrix
temp$VidID <- str_sub(file_list[i], 9, -5)

However, this just adds a new column into the image matrix that is just the file name (minus extraneous stuff) repeated 720 times. This prevents all the downstream stuff from working.
I'm at the point where I'm not sure if it's possible to do this with a list of matrices, so I'm willing to alter how I'm importing the files.

Have you tried using names function / property? Something like names(temp$[[length(temp)]] <- "set name". Minimal example: L <- list(); L <- append(L,"A"); names(L[[length(L)]]) <- "name A".

However, the solution in my previous comment will not work for matrices. For matrices you could go similarly:
L <- list()
v.names <- NULL # separate vector for names
inside for...
M <- matrix(2,3,2)
L <- append(L,list(M))
v.names <- c(v.names,"mat.M")
A <- matrix(0,2,3)
L <- append(L,list(A))
v.names <- c(v.names,"mat.A")
names(L) <- v.names
Now you can get names property of list and filter it.

Would you be open to a solution that treats your matrices as geographic raster data?  This problem sounds like it is perfectly suited to the "terra" and "tmap" packages. Also, would you be able to provide the raw data of a few (maybe just 3) of the matrices?  This can be accomplished by reading in a matrix, and then running dput(<the name of a matrix>) and posting the output of each matrix's call to `dput()`` to your question?

@WojciechArtichowicz read.delim outputs data frames, not matrices. Your comment might be a solution.

Here is a potential solution using a geographic information systems approach.  First as noted in the comments above, I am reading in as a data.frame instead of as a matrix.  Second, I collect all of the data as a multiband raster.  This allows me to then name each band of the raster with the species name of the mammal.  Finally, I use the functions of tmap to create a three faceted map, one facet per species to display the results.  Here is a reproducible example using fake probability of occurrence data for moose, elk, and wolves.  Note, even though I am using a geographic information systems approach, there is no need to have geographic data associated with these data.  Below is the reproducible example:
library(terra)
library(tmap)

set.seed(48)
Mat_1<-as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(51840, 500, .50), nrow=720, ncol=720))
Mat_2<-as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(51840, 500, .25), nrow=720, ncol=720))
Mat_3<-as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(51840, 500, .45), nrow=720, ncol=720))

tmpdir<-tempdir()

if(!dir.exists(tmpdir)){
  dir.create(tmpdir)
}

write.csv(Mat_1, paste(tmpdir, "/Cervus canadensis.csv", sep=""),row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(Mat_2, paste(tmpdir, "/Alces alces.csv", sep=""),row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(Mat_3, paste(tmpdir, "/Canis lupus.csv", sep=""),row.names = FALSE)

file_list<-list.files(tmpdir, pattern="*.csv", full.names = TRUE)
spp_list<-list.files(tmpdir, pattern="*.csv", full.names = FALSE)

rastlist<-list()

for(i in 1:length(file_list)){
  temp <- read.csv(file = paste(file_list[i]))
  
  #change column names
  names(temp) <- c(1:ncol(temp))
  
  #rescale values between 0 and 1
  temp <- rast(nrows=nrow(temp), ncols=ncol(temp), vals=temp/max(temp))
  
  # Time to create/add to list
  rastlist <- append(rastlist, list(temp))
  
}

rasts<-do.call(c, rastlist)
names(rasts)<-substring(spp_list, 1, nchar(spp_list)-4)

tmap_mode("plot")

tm_shape(rasts)+
  tm_raster(palette="viridis", title="Probability of Mammal Occurrence")

And here is what the output map looks like:

